# zuul + okta +springboot - OKTA redirect uri issue 404

Tags: spring-security, spring-security-oauth2, netflix-zuul, okta

I have Zuul server running on port 8080, a service running on 8082 and I've configured the following in OKTA

```
Login redirect URIs 
http://localhost:8080/api/service-A/port    
Logout redirect URIs 
Login initiated by App Only
Initiate login URI http://localhost:8080/login
```

that redirect uri works if I access it without enabling @EnableOAuth2Sso
I've also tried to just do localhost:8080 (but thats not mapped)

I do not have a UI so I'm counting on OKTA's default form.

I've also added all of these properties in my zuul app.prop

```
security.oauth2.client.client-id={yourClientId}
security.oauth2.client.client-secret={yourClientSecret}
security.oauth2.client.access-token-uri=https://dev-187722.oktapreview.com/oauth2/default/v1/token
security.oauth2.client.user-authorization-uri=https://dev-187722.oktapreview.com/oauth2/default/v1/authorize
security.oauth2.client.scope=openid profile email
security.oauth2.resource.user-info-uri=https://dev-187722.oktapreview.com/oauth2/default/v1/userinfo
security.oauth2.resource.token-info-uri=https://dev-187722.oktapreview.com/oauth2/default/v1/introspect
security.oauth2.resource.prefer-token-info=false
```

but I still keep getting this error message: **The 'redirect_uri' parameter must be an absolute URI that is whitelisted in the client app settings.**
I dont even get the login form, just a 404

localhost:8080 is set as a trusted origin (as seen below)

```
SpringOauth 144 http://localhost:8080/
```

sources: I pretty much followed this guide https://developer.okta.com/blog/2018/02/13/secure-spring-microservices-with-oauth

Comment: When you’re redirected to Okta and see the invalid redirect URI error, the URI it’s sending will be in your address bar. This value needs to be whitelisted in your Okta app. I’m guessing the value is http://localhost:8080/login.

Answer (score 0):

1. Can you please double check that your edge-service (zuul) is running on http://localhost:8080/ ?
2. On okta console , you should have :
   Login redirect URIs : http://localhost:8080/login

Hope this helps